# how to solve balanced parenthesis with successfully evaluating escape sequence in single quotation marks?

Tags: c++

i write the code for balanced parenthesis in C++ and i would have success output. so i wanted to one more step. adding the code that successfully evaluating escape sequence in single quotation marks. but it didn't work successfully and i didn't know what is wrong. and sorry for my poor quality in English. because i am Asian.

```
bool checkMatching(std::string ch) {

std::stack<char> check;
int nline = 0;
int ncount = 0;

bool quot = false;
bool Bigquot = false;
bool note1 = false;
bool note2 = false;

for (int i = 0; i < ch.length(); i++) {

    if (ch[i] == '\\') {
        i++;
        continue;           // this code is for escape sequence 
    }


    if (ch[i] == '\/' && ch[i + 1] == '\/' && note1 == false && note2 == false) note1 = true;      
    else if (ch[i] == '\n') {
        note1 = false;
        nline++;
    }
    
    if (ch[i] == '\/' && ch[i + 1] == '*'&& note1 == false && note2 == false) note2 = true;
    else if (ch[i] == '*' && ch[i + 1] == '\/' && note2 == true) note2 == false;


    if (ch[i] == '\'' && note1 == false && note2 == false&& quot == false) quot = true;
    else if (ch[i] == '\'' && quot == true ) {
            quot = false;
            ncount++;
        }
    

    if (ch[i] == '\"' && note1 == false && note2 == false && Bigquot == false) Bigquot = true;
    else if (ch[i] == '\"' && Bigquot == true) Bigquot = false;

    if ((ch[i] == '(' || ch[i] == '{' || ch[i] == '[') &&
        (note1 == false && note2 == false && quot == false && Bigquot == false)) {
        check.push(ch[i]);
    }
    
    if ((ch[i] == ')' || ch[i] == '}' || ch[i] == ']') &&
        (note1 == false && note2 == false && quot == false && Bigquot == false)) {

        if (check.empty()) {
            nline++;
            std::cout << "Error," << " Line_count : " << nline <<"," << " quotes_count : " << ncount;
            return !check.empty();
        }

        char prev = check.top();
        check.pop();

        if ((prev == '(' && ch[i] == ')') ||
            (prev == '{' && ch[i] == '}') ||
            (prev == '[' && ch[i] == ']')) {
            
            //ncount++;
        }


    }
    
}

if (check.empty()) std::cout << "OK," << " Line_count : " << nline << "," << " quotes_count : " << ncount;
else    std::cout << "Error," << " Line_count : " << nline << "," << " quotes_count : " << ncount;


return check.empty();
```

}

Comment: You don't need to escape the `'/'` character.

Comment: You don't need to escape any of characters except `'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.